# JPA (Hibernate) mapping of Map. What annotations should I use for java.util.Map mapping?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, mapping, many-to-many

Tables structure:

```
TABLE products (id (PK), name, price);

TABLE orders (id (PK), customer_id, user_id);

//product_quantity is quantity of product in particular order
TABLE products_to_orders (product_id, order_id, product_quantity
  PRIMARY KEY (product_id, order_id),
  FOREIGN KEY (product_id) REFERENCES products (id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
  FOREIGN KEY (order_id) REFERENCES orders (id) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

Here is my `Order.java`:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "orders")
public class Order extends BaseEntity {
...
//this map holds Products and their quantities in order;
        @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
        @JoinTable(
                name = "products_to_orders"
                ,joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "order_id")
                ,inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "product_id") //it seems that i don't need this line
        )
        @MapKeyJoinColumn(name = "product_id")
        @Column(name = "product_quantity")
        private Map<Product, Integer> productQuantityMap;
...
```

My mapping using those annotations doesn't work. It gives an exception:

> Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Use of @OneToMany or
>   @ManyToMany targeting an unmapped class:
>   com.malikov.shopsystem.model.Order.productQuantityMap[java.lang.Integer]

So I am not able to manage how to properly annotate this Map. I would appreciate your help a lot!
Here is link to my repsitory on GitHub
https://github.com/malikov-yurii/online-shop-management-system.git

UPDATE. There are two right solutions (from Neil and Maciej):

```
  Variation 1:
    @ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(
            name = "products_to_orders"
            ,joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "order_id")
    )
    @MapKeyJoinColumn(name = "product_id")
    @Column(name = "product_quantity")
    private Map<Product, Integer> productQuantityMap;

  Variation 2
    @ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @CollectionTable(name = "products_to_orders")
    @MapKeyJoinColumn(name = "product_id")
    @Column(name = "product_quantity")
    private Map<Product, Integer> productQuantityMap;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this configuration. @ElementCollection instead of @ManyToMany and @CollectionTable instead of @JoinTable

```
@ElementCollection
@CollectionTable(name = "products_to_orders"        
@MapKeyJoinColumn(name = "product_id")
@Column(name = "product_quantity")
private Map<Product, Integer> productQuantityMap;
```

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't the documentation for your chosen JPA provider include how to map your Map field? You can see it described in [this documentation](http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform_5_0/jpa/orm/one_to_many_map.html#join_pc_simple) provided by DataNucleus JPA. In simple terms you need to include

```
@ElementCollection
@JoinTable
Map<Product, Integer> productQuantityMap;
```

(as well as any additional annotations if you want to configure the schema, but these are the essential bits).

Comment: thanks for your reply, I tried
ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
   JoinTable(
            name = "products_to_orders"
            ,joinColumns = JoinColumn(name = "order_id")
            ,inverseJoinColumns = JoinColumn(name = "product_id")
    )
and different combinations of using of ElementCollection, but it doesn't work..
Examples from your link are not same as my situation.
I do my best, but I can't solve this problem

Comment: Define "not same as my situation". You have a key which is an Entity (presumably) and a value that is a basic. That is what is covered by that link. Works for me, so kindly define how your JPA provider doesn't handle it like that and what error you now get ... because your question relates to using ManyToMany which is not in the docs i showed

Comment: Sorry, you were right, i checked that. Thanks for your time and attention!
I'll attach to question both solutions from you and Maciej